# How to run compare_exchange_weak on an std::atomic<bool>?

Tags: c++, atomic

I've tried running

```
std::atomic<bool> set(false);
```

Then later on in a function I try using:

```
  Process::signalsDone.compare_exchange_weak(false, true, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Why does this, when compiling, cause an error message?

```
 error C2664: 'bool std::atomic<bool>::compare_exchange_weak(_Ty &,const _Ty,const std::memory_order,const std::memory_order) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from 'bool' to '_Ty &'
        with
        [
            _Ty=bool
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\atomic(1636): note: see declaration of 'std::atomic<bool>::compare_exchange_weak'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `compare_exchange_weak` [is a `T&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange).

You can't bind a literal like `false` to a `T&`; you've never been able to do that.

Instead, make a variable of type `bool` that can be passed to the function by reference. The variable's value will be altered to the actual value of the `atomic_bool` if the comparison fails.